# Listing all files matching a full-path pattern in R

Tags: regex, r, path

I am trying to obtain the list of files matching a **full-path** pattern. So far, I have used list.files() but it did not work.

Let's assume that we have the following directory organization:

```
results
   |- A
   |  |- data-1.csv
   |  |- data-2.csv
   |
   |- B
      |- data-1.csv
      |- data-2.csv
```

Then the following command:

```
list.files(pattern='data-.*\\.csv', recursive=TRUE)
```

will return all the files matching the pattern. This works, but the problem appears when using a **full-path** pattern. For instance, if I want to obtain all the CSV files from directory *results/A*, I could do:

```
list.files(pattern='results/A/data-.*\\.csv', recursive=TRUE)
```

This does not work, though. Somehow, it seems like R is not able to use a full-path pattern as a regular expression. In this case, the solution could be to just use *results/A* as the base path. But in more complex problems, that cannot be done. For instance, at some point we may want to match the subdirectories containing only characters:

```
list.files(pattern='results/[A-Z]+/data-.*\\.csv', recursive=TRUE)
```

Is it possible to do this in R?

**UPDATE:** After using ad hoc solutions for a while, I decided to stop typing the same again and again. So, I created a [library](https://github.com/betabandido/exptools) for simplifying this task.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, note that you are not using regular expression patterns. Your first example should be:

```
list.files(pattern='data-.*\\.csv', recursive=TRUE)
```

Then, it seems the pattern matching inside `list.files`  is applied to the file basenames (i.e., not including the directory path) so you could split the task into:

1. Find all files matching the basename only, return their full paths:

   ```
   basename.matches <- list.files(pattern='data-.*\\.csv', recursive=TRUE,
                                  full.names = TRUE)
   basename.matches
   # [1] "./results/A/data-1.csv" "./results/A/data-2.csv" "./results/B/data-1.csv"
   # [4] "./results/B/data-2.csv"
   ```
2. Keep only those that match the expected directory(ies):

   ```
   full.matches <- grep(pattern='^\\./results/A/', basename.matches, value = TRUE)
   full.matches
   # [1] "./results/A/data-1.csv" "./results/A/data-2.csv"
   ```

Comment: You are totally right. Thank you for spotting that. Your two-step solution is similar to what I was planning to do if, as it seems it is the case, there is no support for full-path patterns in R. However, if the regular expression points to an absolute path, list.files will not work. For instance, '/tmp/[A-Z]+/data-.*\\.csv'.  I guess I can always extract the beginning of the path '/tmp/' and use that as the 'path' parameter for list.files, but I was wondering if R already provides something like that.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do this with only `list.files` because it loops over each element in `path` and applies the regular expression to the files contained therein.  But since the `path` argument to `list.files` can accept a vector, you can use that to solve your problem.

```
dirs <- grep("[A-Z]+$",list.dirs("results",recursive=FALSE),value=TRUE)
list.files(dirs, "data-.*\\.csv", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an even simpler solution:

`Sys.glob(file.path(results, "[A-Z]", "data-*.csv"))`

Answer (score 1):

I will use

```
paths <- list.files(results, pattern= glob2rx("*data-*.csv$*"), full.names=T, recursive=T)
```