# Reading multiple csv files from a folder with R using regex

Tags: r, regex

I wish to use `R` to read multiple `csv` files from a single folder.  If I wanted to read every `csv` file I could use:

```
list.files(folder, pattern="*.csv")
```

See, for example, these questions:

[Reading multiple csv files from a folder into a single dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819433/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-into-a-single-dataframe-in-r)

[Importing multiple .csv files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r)

However, I only wish to read one of four subsets of the files at a time.  Below is an example grouping of four files each for three models.

```
JS.N_Nov6_2017_model220_N200.csv
JS.N_Nov6_2017_model221_N200.csv
JS.N_Nov6_2017_model222_N200.csv
my.IDs.alt_Nov6_2017_model220_N200.csv
my.IDs.alt_Nov6_2017_model221_N200.csv
my.IDs.alt_Nov6_2017_model222_N200.csv
parms_Nov6_2017_model220_N200.csv
parms_Nov6_2017_model221_N200.csv
parms_Nov6_2017_model222_N200.csv
supN_Nov6_2017_model220_N200.csv
supN_Nov6_2017_model221_N200.csv
supN_Nov6_2017_model222_N200.csv
```

If I only wish to read, for example, the `parms` files I try the following, which does not work:

```
list.files(folder, pattern="parm*.csv")
```

I am assuming that I may need to use `regex` to read a given group of the four groups present, but I do not know.

How can I read each of the four groups separately?

**EDIT**

I am unsure whether I would have been able to obtain the solution from answers to this question:

[Listing all files matching a full-path pattern in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353540/listing-all-files-matching-a-full-path-pattern-in-r)

I may have had to spend a fair bit of time brushing up on `regex` to apply those answers to my problem.  The answer provided below by `Mako212` is outstanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all files matching a full-path pattern in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353540/listing-all-files-matching-a-full-path-pattern-in-r); in particular, I think the first answer to that question will solve your issue -- it looks like you need to escape the period (right now your pattern is "parm", then one occurrence of any character, then "csv")

Comment: Get all the filenames, *list.files* returns them in alpha ordered, then use *split*, and read in chunks using *lapply* or *forloop*, e.g.: `myFiles <- 1:12; split(myFiles, ceiling(seq_along(myFiles)/3))`

Comment: For "parm": `list.files(folder, pattern="^parm.*?\\.csv")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick REGEX 101 explanation:

For the case of matching the beginning and end of the string, which is all you need to do here, the following prinicples apply to match files that are `.csv` and start with `parm`:

`list.files(folder, pattern="^parm.*?\\.csv")`

`^` asserts we're at the beginning of the string, so `^parm` means match `parm`, but only if it's at the beginning of the string.

`.*?` means match anything up until the next part of the pattern matches. In this case, match until we see a period `\\.`

`.` means match any character in REGEX, so we need to escape it with `\\` to match the literal `.` (note that in R you need the double escape `\\`, in other languages a single escape `\` is sufficienct).

Finally `csv` means match `csv` after the `.`. If we were going to be really thorough, we might use `\\.csv$` using the `$` to indicate the end of the string. You'd need the dollar sign if you had other files with an extension like `.csv2`. `\\.csv` would match `.csv2`, where as `\\.csv$` would not.

In your case, you could simply replace `parm` in the REGEX pattern with `JS`, `my`, or `supN` to select one of your other file types.

Finally, if you wanted to match a subset of your total file list, you could use the `|` logical "or" operator:

`list.files(folder, pattern = "^(parm|JS|supN).*?\\.csv")`

Which would return all the file names except the ones that start with `my`

Answer (score 3):

The `list.files` statement shown in the question is using globs but `list.files` accepts [regular expressions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html), not [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

**Sys.glob** To use globs use [Sys.glob](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.glob.html) like this:

```
olddir <- setwd(folder)
parm <- lapply(Sys.glob("parm*.csv"), read.csv)
```

`parm` is now a list of data frames read in from those files.

**glob2rx** Note that the [glob2rx](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/glob2rx.html) function can be used to convert globs to regular expressions:

```
parm <- lapply(list.files(folder, pattern = glob2rx("parm*.csv")), read.csv)
```

Comment: Note that any parameters of the read.csv() function can be passed as additional arguments within the lapply() function. E.g., use the following if you have pipe-separated file: `lapply(list.files(folder, pattern = glob2rx("parm*.csv")), read.csv, sep='|')`