# read multiple csv files with timestamp in R

Tags: r, csv, file, timestamp

I found several questions about how to read multiple csv files into R. However, they are all named sequentially. Now, I've got files with time stamps. So I find it difficult to find a way to read them all in. Can somebody help?
For example, they look like this:

```
99_Experiment Version A_2020-06-02_12h26.48.883.csv
```

I don't need the date, it was just automatically generated. Is there an easy way to remove it? Then all files would be named in the same format (_Experiment Version A.csv with ascending numbers at the front) and I can maybe use one of the other posts to read them

Comment: Are all files in one folder? If yes: are there other .csv-files you don't want to import?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189714/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-with-r-using-regex)

Comment: @MartinGal yes they are all in one folder and there is no other file that I don't want to import, I need them all :D

Answer (score 3):

Below are some options you can try depending on how you want to import your data into R.

Note: make sure to set your working director to the folder your files are contained in with the `setwd()` function.

Below will result in each data frame as a separate element in a single list:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

If you then want to combine those list elements into a single data frame, you can use functions like `do.call(rbind,...)`, `dplyr::bind_rows()`, or `data.table::rbindlist()`.

If you really want your `.csv` file as a separate data frames you could do the following with `assign()`:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Or you could use the below code which does not rely upon the `assign()` function:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
         read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I saw this solution earlier, but if I use the functions you suggested I only get a data frame with one column (the entries of the earlier columns are separated by , each)

Comment: How many columns is it supposed to have?  Is there a first column that is being read as a row label?  If so you can set `row.names=FALSE` within the `read.csv()` function.  Also, you can set `sep=","` which should tell the function your data is seperated by commas.  Not sure if this will work though, `sep=","` is supposed to be the default.

Comment: It's supposed to have 63 columns, and no, the first one is already filled with data, I have a header.

Comment: Does `temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")` at least generate a complete list of your `.csv` files?

Comment: Did you try adjusting  `read.csv(temp[i])` to read `read.csv(temp[i], head = TRUE, sep = ",")` in the second chunk of code I posted?  The result would be the line: `for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i], head = TRUE, sep = ","))`.

Comment: If this ended up working, please select this answer to close out the question.  Best wishes!