# regular expression to filter and read files with specific names

Tags: regex

I need to read a directory containing a number of csv files .
I need to read ONLY those files such as : `ABC*.csv` or `XYZ*.csv`

Was trying as per this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189714/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-with-r-using-regex)
However when I tried it in postman it gave no results :
`^(ABC|XYZ).*?\\.csv$")`

I know this is a very simple check but am struggling with it ...

Edit1 : This is a simple Java application and does not involve R ( linked question )

Edit2 : here is the screenprint of what I am trying in notepad++
[image]

Comment: What's your actual Java code? Your `^(ABC|XYZ).*?\\.csv$")` has an unbalanced quote and parenthesis.

Comment: i am trying it directly in notepad++

Comment: I think there are pattern errors on your regex, try `^(ABC|XYZ).*?\.csv$` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Filters* input box does not support regular expressions.

As explained in the [Notepad++ documentation](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#find-in-files-tab):

> The **Filters** list is a space-separated list of wildcard expressions that cmd.exe can understand, like `*.doc foo.*`.

So in your case you would want to enter:

```
ABC*.csv XYZ*.csv
```